# To compute $\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}$ without L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

We suppose that have this limit of a succession $n\in \Bbb N$ with real terms
$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}$$
Now this limit have the value $e$. In fact I have done these steps remebering that
$f^g=e^{g\ln f}$

$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}=\lim_n e^{ \frac{\ln (1+n)}{\ln n}}$$

Without L'Hospital's rule, I do not remember the result of
$$\lim_n \frac{\ln (1+n)}{\ln n}$$
(related here - I have seen this now [Limit of $\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln (n)}$ without L'Hôpital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085891/limit-of-undersetn-to-infty-textlim-frac-ln-n1-ln-n-without)) hence I had due to compute the
$$\frac{\ln (1+n)}{\ln n}$$ when $n$ is more larger than 1. In fact if I choose $n=1000$, for example, I will have $\frac{\ln (1+n)}{\ln n} \to 1$ and
$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}=\lim_n e^{ \frac{\ln (1+n)}{\ln n}}=e^1=e.\,\square$$

---

This way I do not like very much; hence I have tried another way to solve

$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}$$
being

$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac 1n}=e \tag 1$$

Thus, if I remember well, $\lim\limits_n \frac n{\ln n}=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_n \frac{\ln n}n=0$, and

$$\lim_n (1+n)^{\frac1{\ln n}}=\lim_n \left[(1+n)^{\frac1{n}}\right]^{\frac n{\ln n}}=e^\infty=+\infty\neq e.$$
Actually I do not see my mistake. Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ (`\lim_{n\to\infty}`)?

Comment: @J.G. $n\in \Bbb N$. :-( you're right but I had written a succession.

Comment: You'll find $\ln(1+n)=\ln n+\ln(1+1/n)$ useful.

Comment: @Sebastiano $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\ln(n)}\neq \infty$

Comment: @J.G. Meantime hi. Yes, of course. But I have not understood the last steps unrelated from your comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano sorry i misunderstood

Comment: @mathboy1296 I had seen $\infty$,

Comment: Hint: as $n\to\infty$, what are the respective behaviours of $\ln(1+1/n),\,\ln n$? So what about $1+\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n}$?

Comment: @J.G. the ratio is $0$ because have the numerator 0. But I have not understood the mistakes after the rule in the question :-(

Comment: I really hate these "do _____ without ______" questions.

Comment: @K.defaoite I have done any efforts :-( and you have right. +1 for comments and surely other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=e$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n)^{1/n}\to1$. So the limit ends up not being $e^\infty$, but of the form $1^\infty$, which is [indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: Ah now i have understood.  However i am curiosus if exist another way considering my steps without my mistake. At the end i not understand the reason of the downvote from a unknown user.

Comment: @Sebastiano I can't explain the downvote, but since $1^\infty$ is indeterminate you can't get the limit with your strategy, except perhaps with a different factorization of the exponent $1/\ln n$.

Answer (score 1):

I always treat limits of this form by computing the limit of the logarithm, so we want to consider
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln n}
$$
If we consider instead of the sequence the function limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln x}
$$
we know that if this one exists, then it's the same of the limit of the sequence (the converse is generally not true). Now we can perform the substitution $x=1/t$ and note that
$$
\ln(1+1/t)=\ln(t+1)-\ln t
$$
so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln t-\ln(1+t)}{\ln t}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\Bigl(1-\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\ln t}\Bigr)=1
$$
because the fraction is $0/\infty$.

Thus we have proved that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n)^{1/\ln n}=e^1=e
$$